# Is it possible to display an image to screen in ASM language, without using interrupts?

Tags: performance, assembly, nasm, x86-16, bare-metal

Is it possible to display pixels to the screen or play a beep in the speakers to screen in ASM language, without using any BIOS/DOR/... interrupts ?

Comment: It is only possible if there is a screen (or speaker) on the device in question.  Anything that can be done in any languages can be done in asm as that is ulitimately what all other languages that actually run reduce to.

Comment: So, how to display pixel onto the screen in asm without any interrupts ? I dod not found any tutorial

Comment: On x86 with standard graphics look for VGA tutorials. See for example [this one](https://files.osdev.org/mirrors/geezer/osd/graphics/modes.c).

Comment: @mpo What kind of computer with what sort of graphics card are you programming for?

Comment: you have to do it the same way that you would with an operating system.  you have code that knows the specific board/chip and simply writes control registers and pixel data and it shows up on the screen.  you wont find any recent tutorials for an x86 system, but other systems it is easy to find.   in the vga days it was documented and fairly simple.

Comment: there is no real demand for such tutorials, so you wont find any.  current video cards are not necessarily openly documented, although you can look at an open source driver and figure it out.

Comment: @old_timer: Modern PCs still have enough hardware support to pretend to be VGA, even for hardware drivers (not using firmware calls).  That's how OSes can portably do 640x480 graphics, for example.  And there are tutorials for that (https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware), doing mode-setting without `int` calls but instead writing to the VGA registers. (Which may actually trigger a System Management Interrupt, but [the actual VGA framebuffer is "real", even text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521819/does-modern-pc-video-hardware-support-vga-text-mode-in-hw-or-does-the-bios-emul))

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, agreed. various ways to do this, and these modes have been documented for decades, the OP just didnt look...beyond those modes though, it is much worse today because you have gpus as well as other factors that you need to know from the vendor.  put some text or some pixels in an ega/vga mode, somewhat trivial...yes

Comment: as far as the title question the answer is obvious, of course, that is how it works now.  software interrupts just call code.  drivers are code, applications are code.  the processor only supports machine code,  and you can generate that from assembly language...so it is possible yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but useless, as each PC is equipped with firmware (BIOS or UEFI) which does the most tedious work.
Many years ago I disassembled PC/XT BIOS code of [Int 10/AH=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) just to learn how to switch Hercules card into graphic mode using bare metal, i.e. instructions IN and OUT applied to [CRT ports](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/900-video_graphics_array_i_o_ports.html).

Most information about hardware I found in [TechHelp](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/3-tech_topics.html), for instance the chapter  [PC Sounds / Speaker Support](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/903-pc_sounds___speaker_support.html) shows how to **play a tone on motherboard speaker** by sending a square wave with `OUT 61h,AL` and toggling bit 1 of `AL`. Quoting TechHelp:

```
The speaker is connected to PPI port B, port 61H.
Set bit 1 to pulse the speaker out and 
clear bit 1 to bring the speaker back to normal. 

         in    al,61H     ;get current value
  again: or    al,02H     ;set bit 2 to pulse it out
         out   61H, al
         mov   cx,1000H
  delay1:loop  delay1     ;wait a little while
         and   al,0fdH    ;clear bit 2 to pulse it back in
         out   61H, al
         mov   cx,1000H
  delay2:loop  delay2     ;wait a little while
         jmp   again
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers like this.  Stack Overflow answers must be useful on their own, even if all links go down.